# Tag-lib issue with Struts2 and Tomcat 8

Tags: eclipse, jsp, struts2

I have been searching for days to resolve this issue.  I have used Struts2 for years, but now I am at a new company and trying to get Struts2 set up in my development environment.  I don't have a choice as to what gets installed.  We have an extremely controlled environment so it's totally out of my hands.  However, I will attempt to install the environment on my personal computer and see what happens.

I have Eclipse LUNA (4.4.2), Apache Tomcat 8.0.38 and Java version 1.8.0_92 installed on my workstation.  In Eclipse I have a Dynamic Web Project set up using Maven.

In Maven I just left the configuration as provided by the tutorial.  It is bringing in javax.servlet-api v3.1.0 and struts2-core v2.3.20.  The Maven Dependencies are included in the Web Deployment Assembly.  I have checked the directory after Tomcat unpacks the WAR file.  Struts2 core is definitely there.

I get no errors or warnings in the Eclipse project.  However when I attempt to execute the first jsp I get an error 500 from Tomcat with "Unable to find taglib "s" for URI: /struts-tags".

My struts.xml file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
  <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
     value="false" />

  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
  <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
      value="ApplicationResources" />

  <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="login"
          class="org.o7planning.tutorial.struts2xml.action.LoginAction">
          <result name="success">/WEB-INF/pages/UserInfo.jsp</result>
          <result name="error">/WEB-INF/pages/Login.jsp</result>
      </action>
  </package>  

 </struts>
```

The web.xml file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

 <display-name>Struts2XML</display-name>


 <filter>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
   <filter-class>
             org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
   </filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/pages/Login.jsp</welcome-file>

</web-app>
```

And the jsp contains:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Struts 2 - Login Application </title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Struts 2 - Login Application</h2>
<s:actionerror />
<s:form action="/login" method="post">
  <s:textfield name="username" key="label.username" size="20" />
  <s:password name="password" key="label.password" size="20" />
  <s:submit method="execute" key="label.login" align="center" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Every question I have found, and there have been many, has revolved around Eclipse.  I don't have that problem.  I'm not getting any Eclipse messages regarding this and all the files appear to be in the right place. So I'm stumped!!

Contents of the Maven pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.codejava.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringStrutsDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.2.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <struts2-version>2.5.1</struts2-version>
    <javax-servlet-api-version>3.1.0</javax-servlet-api-version>
    <javax-servlet-jsp-version>2.3.1</javax-servlet-jsp-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <version>${struts2-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts2-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax-servlet-api-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax-servlet-jsp-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

List of jar files in WEB-INF/lib

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.3.jar
sm-commons-3.3.jar
sm-tree-3.3.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang3-3.4.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
freemarker-2.3.23.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.1.jar
libs.txt
log4j-api-2.5.jar
ognl-3.1.8.jar
spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar
struts2-core-2.5.1.jar
struts2-spring-plugin-2.5.1.jar
```

I am unable to try other platforms on this machine.  What we can install is completely out of our hands.  We don't even have admin rights on our development workstations.  What I have is what I have to use.  We have a software portal that performs installs of "approved" software.  If there is a mistake in the install I have to discover it, prove it and go to the support group and request a fix.

Comment: did you attached all strtus based "struts2-core-.jar" ?

Comment: There is one struts core jar file.  It contains all the DTD's for the Struts tags.  And yes, it is definitely in /WEB-INF/lib

Comment: try to upload latest struts jar because your code works for me when i add struts2-core-2.1.8.jar

Comment: Can you try (at home or wherever) that WAR in another container (eg. Tomcat7, Glassfish, etc... )? Also edit the question by adding all your jars

Comment: Question updated as requested.

Comment: Remove spring libs from the project.

Comment: I downloaded and installed Tomcat 7 last night and moved the WAR file in there, with no changes.  The web page came up just fine.  So now I know there is an issue with Tomcat 8.  Is it a setting in Tomcat or something different I have to do with the controls (XML files)?  I'm still investigating.

Comment: I took the Spring jar files out of the WAR file and deployed to the Tomcat 8 instance.  It didn't change the result.  Still getting the **"Unable to find taglib"** error.